# Dynamically specifying a serializer based on a property of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to dynamically specify a serializer based on a property of a model (within a parent serializer):

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.setup do |config|
  config.embed = :ids
  config.embed_in_root = true
end

class DocumentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :name, :document_layout

  if attributes[:document_layout] === 'portrait'
    has_many :pages, serializer: PortraitPageSerializer
  elsif attributes[:document_layout] === 'landscape'
    has_many :pages, serializer: LandscapePageSerializer
  end

end
```

but this doesn't seem to work (I guess attributes isn't simply a hash).

Is there another way to access the value? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: How did you pick the DocumentSerializer?  Did you just render a document?

Comment: Yep in my controller I'm calling:

render json: @documents, status: :ok

Comment: I guess perhaps it would be more sane to use the same serializer and just have it leave some columns blank depending on the document_layout

Answer (score 1):

Was thinking more about this (it's been a while since I was working on Serializers), would this work?

```
class DocumentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :name
  has_many :portrait_pages, key: pages, serializer: PortraitPageSerializer
  has_many :landscape_pages, key: pages, serializer: LandscapePageSerializer

  def portrait_pages
    pages if object.document_layout === 'portrait'
  end

  def landscape_pages
    pages if object.document_layout === 'landscape'
  end

end
```

Another option here - subclass your document to have a LandscapeDocument and PortraitDocument.  This could be based on type, which lines up with your document_layout field.  A thought...

Comment: Hi Swards, I think you're right... Rails STI is probably the way forward as they can all inherit from a base class but then I can have separate serializers for each type